# Old novel about earth overpopulation

Tags: story-identification, novel

I believe the novel is set in future Chicago. People live in one room cubes and are given daily medications. A man is taken to a "treatment facility" only to find out he has been used to fertilize women whose babies would be genetically altered to be miniature. There is a war between the miniatures and at some point the man reunites with a miniature who turns out to be his son.

Answer (score 11):

**Old novel about earth overpopulation**

["This Crowded Earth"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8431), a 1958 novella by [Robert Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bloch); etext at [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/25776), audio at [LibriVox](https://archive.org/details/thiscrowdedearth_0903_librivox). Any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?8431) look familiar?

**I believe the novel is set in future Chicago.**

Yes. They call it "Chicagee", perhaps because it's a megametropolis extending from *Chicag*o to Milwauk*ee*

> The telescreen lit up promptly at eight a.m. Smiling Brad came on with his usual greeting. "Good morning—it's a beautiful day in Chicagee!"
>
> Harry Collins rolled over and twitched off the receiver. "This I doubt," he muttered. He sat up and reached into the closet for his clothing.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Sometimes he wished he worked in the New Philly area, where a four-hour day was the rule. But he supposed that wouldn't mean any real saving in time, because he'd have to live further out. What was the population in New Philly now? Something like 63,000,000, wasn't it? Chicagee was much smaller—only 38,000,000, this year.
>
> *This* year. Harry shook his head and took a gulp of the Instantea. Yes, this year the population was 38,000,000, and the boundaries of the community extended north to what used to be the old Milwaukee and south past Gary. What would it be like *next* year, and the year following?

**People live in one room cubes**

> Visitors—particularly feminine ones—were always exclaiming over the advantages of Harry's apartment. "So convenient," they would say. "Everything handy, right within reach. And think of all the extra steps you save!"
>
> Of course most of them were just being polite and trying to cheer Harry up. They knew damned well that he wasn't living in one room through any choice of his own. The Housing Act was something you just couldn't get around; not in Chicagee these days. A bachelor was entitled to one room—no more and no less. And even though Harry was making a speedy buck at the agency, he couldn't hope to beat the regulations.

**and are given daily medications.**

> Harry reached for a container in the cabinet and poured out a couple of aspirystamines. That ought to help the headache. At least until he got to the office. Then he could start with the daily quota of yellowjackets. Meanwhile, getting out on the street might help him, too. A shame there wasn't a window in this apartment, but then, what good would it do, really? All he could see through it would be the next apartment.

**A man is taken to a "treatment facility"**

> "This is fine," he told Dr. Manschoff. "If I'd known how well they treated you, I'd have gone couch-happy years ago."
>
> Dr. Manschoff's plump face was impassive, but the little laugh-lines deepened around the edges of his eyes. "Maybe that's why we take such care not to publicize our recent advances in mental therapy," he said. "Everybody would want to get into a treatment center, and then where would we be?"

**only to find out he has been used to fertilize women whose babies would be genetically altered to be miniature.**

> "I was right, eh?" he muttered.
>
> "It looks that way. But I can't understand what's going on. If this isn't just a treatment center, if they're not really interested in my welfare, then what am I doing here?"
>
> "You're taking part in an experiment. This, my friend, is a laboratory. And you are a nice, healthy guinea pig."
>
> "But that doesn't make sense. I haven't been experimented on. They've let me do as I please."
>
> "Exactly. And what do guinea pigs excel at? *Breeding*."

After the experiments on mental patients, the program is extended to the general population:

> "It won't be so bad," Minnie went on. "The shots don't hurt at all, and they make it easier, carrying the baby. They say you don't even get morning sickness or anything. And just think, when we have a kid, we get a chance for a bigger place. We go right on the housing lists. We can have two rooms. A real bedroom, maybe."
>
> Frank stared at her. "Is that all you can think about?" he asked. "A real bedroom?"
>
> "But honey—"
>
> "What about the kid?" he muttered. "How you suppose it's gonna feel? How'd you like to grow up and *not* grow up? How'd you like to be a midget three feet high in a world where everybody else is bigger? What kind of a life you call *that*? I want my son to have a decent chance."
>
> "He will have."
>
> Minnie stared back at him, but she wasn't seeing his face. "Don't you understand, honey? This isn't just something happening to *us*. We're not special. It's happening to everybody, all over the country, all over the world. You seen it in the 'casts, haven't you? Most states, they adopted the laws. And in a couple more years it'll be the only way anyone will ever have kids. Ten, twenty years from now, the kids will be growing up. Ours won't be different then, because from now on all the kids will be just like he is. The same size."

The miniatures are called "Yardsticks":

> Eric sat down behind his desk, grinning. *Yardsticks*. When he was a kid it had been just the other way around. He and the rest of them who didn't get shots in those early days considered themselves to be the normal ones. And *they* did the name-calling. Names like "runt" and "half-pint" and "midgie." But the most common name was the one that stuck—Yardstick. That used to be the worst insult of all.

**There is a war between the miniatures**

> "The Yardsticks are human beings, just like us," Eric said, slowly. "We can't just declare war on them, wipe them out. It's not their *fault* they were born that way."
>
> Wolzek nodded. "I know. Nothing is anybody's fault, really. This whole business began in good faith. Leffingwell and some of the other geniuses saw a problem and offered what they sincerely believed was a solution."
>
> "But it didn't work," Eric murmured.
>
> "Wrong. It worked only too well. That's the trouble. Sure, we eliminated our difficulties on the physical level. In less than thirty years we've reached a point where there's no longer any danger of overcrowding or starvation. But the psychological factor is something we can't cope with. We thought we'd ended war and the possibilities of war a long time ago. But it isn't foreign enemies we must fear today. We've created a nation divided into Davids and Goliaths—and David and Goliath are always enemies."

**and at some point the man reunites with a miniature who turns out to be his son.**

> "So you're a physician, eh?" Harry gazed down into the diminutive face, striving to accept the fact that he was speaking to a mature adult. His own son—his and Sue's—a grown man and a doctor! It seemed incredible. But then, nothing was more incredible than the knowledge that he was actually here, in his child's home.

Comment: An anonymous user proposed this as an edit: _"They call it "Chicagee" because it's a megametropolis extending from **Chicag**o to Milwauk**ee**"_