# A short story involving discrimination based on size

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, toys

I am trying to remember the title of a story I read as a kid. The story, set in the future, revolves around individuals that chose to reduce their size or have kids of smaller than usual stature because the burden on the earth's resources has become too great. Those who do not undergo this procedure and/or allow their children to grow to normal height are discriminated against.

There was another story (or maybe the same tale) where the protagonist was rescued from some menace by his childhood toy, a teddy bear that had come to life or took form somehow.

I believe that this story (or stories) was in an anthology of children's science fiction published in the 1970s, maybe the late 1960s.

Comment: Perhaps ["This Crowded Earth"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8431) by Robert Bloch? You can read it at Project Gutenberg: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/25776

Comment: I don't know if "This Crowded Earth" is the correct answer to this question, but it was my **unaccepted** answer to an old question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134765/old-novel-about-earth-overpopulation

Comment: I believe I've also read this story (but can't remember it's name). I had a hardcover anthology with this story: If I remember, 2 sisters lived with their dad in a cave, until they had to go into the wider world. Everything (cars, tools) were smaller because they were designed for the little people, so the 2 sisters were better at using them than their dad. One of the sisters had a teddy bear. They got caught and were shipped off to some other planet as basically slave labor. But when they got to the new planet, they were rescued by the aliens, who looked just like the one girl's teddy bear.

Answer (score 3):

Suspect this is ["Teddi"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62165) by Andre Norton.

There are the "littles" (small people) and the bear-like "Teddis".

I have it in the 1973 anthology *Way Out*, edited by Roger Elwood.